# How can I ignore big files and push to git repo

Tags: git, github

Before, I used git locally without using `.gitignore`
Afterwards,
I created an `.gitignore` file, and write all unnecessary files in it.
When I push them to git repo, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly error appears.

I dont want to push ignore files, but, somehow git tries to push them to repo.

Please help me, what is my fault? Thanks

Comment: You donts want to push the big files or the `.gitignore` ?

Comment: I dont want to push all files in `.gitignore`

Comment: I came here after googling how to block such Git pushes in the first place. I asked about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72588572/can-i-configure-github-to-block-large-files).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-the-git-repository

Comment: the best answer for it is over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547007/11472644

Answer (score 46, accepted):

GitHub has a [nice article on this](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/). You basically want to remove the files from Git history, but not from the file system.

- If your file was pushed in your last commit, you can do:

  ```
  git rm --cached path/to/your/big/file
  git commit --amend -CHEAD
  git push
  ```
- If not, they recommend using [`BFG`](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)–a tool for cleaning up repositories (*alternative to git-filter-branch*):

  ```
  bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 50M
  ```

  This will remove files bigger than 50M.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the github article! I was missing the `git commit --amend -CHEAD` and was going insane!

Comment: Not sure why all other answers of stackoverflow are more complicated than this