# How to remove big files from old commits in bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

my bitbucket repo got very big (1.6 GB) after I did some awful commits some months ago. I did not realized how serious was the situation (noob..), since a collegue tried to clone it and failed (too big).

I read carefully this post [Why is my git repository so big?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029969/why-is-my-git-repository-so-big) and did the following (as [@Vi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266720/vi) suggested):

- **Detect fat files in my repo history**

  ```
  git rev-list --all --objects |     sed -n $(git rev-list --objects --all | \
  cut -f1 -d' ' | \
  git cat-file --batch-check | \
  grep blob | \
  sort -n -k 3 | \
  tail -n40 | \
  while read hash type size; do 
   echo -n "-e s/$hash/$size/p ";
  done) |
  sort -n -k1
  ```

  Let's say one of the fat files is *mybigfile.gz*
- **Delete mybigfile.gz from repo**

  ```
  git filter-branch -f  --index-filter \
  'git rm --force --cached --ignore-unmatch mybigfile.gz' \
  -- --all
  rm -Rf .git/refs/original && \
  git reflog expire --expire=now --all && \
  git gc --aggressive && \
  git prune
  ```

Actually, it worked since now my local repo directory is 850MB.
The problem is that the remote repository did not change size.
Then I tried to

```
git push origin --force --all
```

but the situation got worse, now my remote repo is 2GB!
How can I solve this awful situation?
Do you suggest to create a new repo or is there something else I can do to sort it out?

Thank you.

**EDIT**: I try to formulate better the problem. Some months ago, I committed  to my repo some big files, several times. When I realised it, I added these files to .gitignore. Then I kept committing to the repo without these file. I was not taking care to the bitbucket warning (your repo is too big). Now, I need to get rid of these files stored in old commits, both locally and remotely. I successfully cleaned up my *local* git directory with the procedure described above. My problem is that when I push to the remote master branch, the *remote* repo is not affected by the local clean up.

EDIT 2:
I tried BFG repo cleaner on my local .git directory

```
java -jar bfg-1.12.3.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M
```

[here](http://pastebin.com/phFj6uSh) the output.

According to this [tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/maintaining-a-git-repository-321848291.html#MaintainingaGitRepository-UsingtheBFGtorewritehistory), this should be enough to remove blobs on remote repo, but actually this did not happen. Locally my repo is slim, but remotely is still huge. I think I'm missing just a step, but do not know how to do it. Do you think it is easier to just create a new repo?

Comment: Have a look at [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

Comment: I answered a similar question some days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32953706/1420197

Comment: @IonicăBizău: Actually, I don't think it is a duplicate question. I do not need to know how to stop uploading files which are now in .gitignore. I need to delete big files I pushed months ago, and that are stored in my remote repo in old commits.

Comment: @user123892 Did you try my answer? It should work for you too, using the BFG tool. Btw, I retracted the close vote. :)

Comment: @IonicăBizău and Enrico Campidoglio I did as you suggested, locally the repo now is slim, but on the bitbucket remote repo nothing changes..

Comment: @user123892 Hmm, try my answer. Not sure if it will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce git repo size on Bitbucket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493071/how-to-reduce-git-repo-size-on-bitbucket)

Comment: @AD7six thank you for redirecting me to this question. Actually I found the solution there, I contacted Bitbucket support and they did "git gc" on their size. Now my remote repo is back to the size of my local one. Anyway, the procedure I followed to clean up local repo is a bit different. I can't say my question is a true duplicate but as I noob I leave the decision to you. Tell what you do think and I'll close the question or not. Thank you again.

Comment: If the other question/answer helped - upvote it/them. If you have a more up-to-date answer for that question answer it. For this question you don't need to take any action about that, if it's closed this question acts as a signpost to the other.

Comment: ok, thank you. I'll upvote the other question. No, the answer to my question does not "update" the other question. Ok, so you think I shall close this post.

Comment: That's not what I said - it takes several people to close a question as a duplicate. In your position I would accept the below answer, or write your own answer and accept that. I would not delete the question myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I just needed to contact [Bitbucket support](https://support.atlassian.com/customer/servicedesk-portal) (they replied in less than an hour). They did:

```
 git gc
```

from their side and my remote repo is back to the local repo size.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments I understood that the problem is fixed locally, but not on remote. Let's do some mad science to force all objects to be dereferenced and garbage collected with the following commands (**create backup first**):

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git push -f
```

Maybe this will clean up the remote repository.

Comment: maybe your solution works, the problem is that my repo now is in read-only mode since bigger then 2.0 GB, so I get 
"conq: repository is in read only mode (over 2 GB size limit).
Transferred: sent 3120, received 2856 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 7432.0, received 6803.1
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists. "
Am I doomed? Thank you for the help.

Comment: @user123892 I took the commands from the BFG output you posted. Probably it helps. If you don't have any issues important data there, just create a new repository... :)