# Can I configure GitHub to block large files

Tags: github

[GitHub documentation on large files](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github) states:

> If you attempt to add or update a file that is larger than 50 MB, you will receive a warning from Git.

> GitHub blocks pushes that exceed 100 MB.

I want to configure it in a way that it blocks any pushes with files larger than some predefined threshold (e.g. 100kb).

Is this possible? How?

Maybe via the branch protection rules? I saw some examples that the branch protection rules can include custom status checks. The status checks, these are GitHub actions? So I could maybe add a custom GitHub CI action which checks for a valid commit (valid = any changed file is below the size limit).

Maybe it's not really possible yet. I also asked [in the official community forum](https://github.com/github-community/community/discussions/18490).

(Note: If possible, I would prefer a pure-Git answer, independent of GitHub. With pure Git, this is possible via a server-side `pre-receive` hook. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57977351/1256452). However, on GitHub, I cannot have a custom pre-receive hook, so this is not an option.)

Comment: Given that you want this to happen *on GitHub*, this becomes a GitHub-only issue, not a Git programming question. I believe the answer to the question as asked is simply "you can't do that" but you should ask the GitHub folks themselves. It might be a selling-feature for them if they could make this configurable (perhaps letting free users turn it down and paid users turn it up depending on mow much they pay ).

Comment: You could, in a pre-push hook, examine each of the commits you're proposing to send to see if any of them contain any files larger than some size. But a pre-push hook is by definition specific to the *client* repository in which one is running `git push` and can always be defeated.

Comment: @torek If there is a pure Git solution (independent of GitHub), this would be even better. I'm not sure what's possible via Git hooks. (That's why I added the 'git' tag back.) Such hook needs to run on the server-side of course. Not sure if there is any Git mechanism for that.

Comment: You cannot have your client Git run a server thing: that would be insecure. (Well, you can run anything they've provided, via some unspecified mechanism such as "branch names matching given patterns" or some such - but we're back to "GitHub must provide this for you".)

Comment: @torek What about the server-side pre-receive hook? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: GitHub have their own and it contains the size check (and protected-branch checks and so on). They won't let you run arbitrary code in their pre-receive hook. But the size check is pretty clearly hardcoded at the moment.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Actually, I just found that they allowed to have a custom pre-receive hook at some earlier point in time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864903/does-github-allow-pre-receive-hooks

Comment: That's about "GitHub Enterprise", which is a thing you buy from them to run on your own server. It's then your machine, so you get to play with the pre-receive hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time I try to commit a large file, it's an error, so I use a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). If you don't have any hooks setup, you can just create the file `/.git/hooks/pre-commit` and put the following bash in it

```bash
#!/bin/bash
max_file_size=10000000
for filename in $(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=A HEAD); do
    filesize=$(stat -c%s "$filename")
    if  (( filesize > max_file_size )) ; then
        echo "The file "$filename" is more than $max_file_size bytes. Git commit cancled." >/dev/stderr
        exit -1
    fi
done
```

Then make the hook executable with `chmod +x /.git/hooks/pre-commit`. This script will block files with more than 10000000 bytes. Some people get fancy with their pre-commits using them to run all sorts of tests and code quality checks, using tools like the [pre-commit framework](https://pre-commit.com/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what are you trying to do. You could always use .gitignore

Here can you find some examples
https://github.com/github/gitignore

You create a file called .gitignore, in the file you add a folder name node_modules, and GitHub won't include it. Or let's say all txt files would be .txt in the .gitignore file.

Comment: I want to block all attempts to push files which are larger than some predefined limit. Also, this check should be done server-side on GitHub, not client-side.

Comment: Check this one out -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382375/github-file-size-limit-changed-6-18-13-cant-push-now , what is your error ?

Comment: See my question. I want to configure this limit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576257/how-to-limit-file-size-on-commit

Comment: Actually more related is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147699/limiting-file-size-in-git-repository). However, it seems that I cannot edit a custom pre-receive hook on GitHub. And any client-side hooks are also no real solutions.

Comment: @Albert: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57977351/1256452) there is the right one; it can be adapted for use in a pre-push hook, but as we have both noted already, that has its own flaws. Short of running your own server or getting a new GitHub feature, though, it's probably the best you'll get.